# Showing the following coordinate rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I show that $\frac{k[x,y,z]}{\langle xz-y^2\rangle}$ is not isomorphic to $k[x,y,z]$? (I want to understand the coordinate ring of this surface) Is there a 'natural' evaluation map that realizes $\langle xz-y^2\rangle$ as its kernel?

Comment: How much do you know about dimension?

Comment: @DylanMoreland,  What a luck! I was also going to ask about dimension of ${A^n}_k$, the affine space of dimension $n$. It s not hard to show that dim $\geq n$. But my question is that in the proofs I see in books, to prove the upper bound, it is first assumed that the there is a maximal finite chain of ascending irreducible closed subsets. But I could not figure out why there must exist a finite chain. I thought it was because $A^n$ is Noetherian, but it seems I need more.

Comment: I changed $< xz-y^2>$ to $\langle xz-y^2\rangle$.  the code is \langle xz-y^2\rangle.  That is standard $\TeX$ usage.

Comment: @Herband: The dimension of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is a different question. Not every noetherian ring has finite dimension. But I don't think that the proofs for $\mathbb{A}^n$ need that the dimension is bounded a priori. Read them again.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, For instance, here is a reference where in the proof, a longest chain is assumed to exist (see page 53, first line of first proof)(here is the link: http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf)

Comment: @Herband: I know that script ;). In the proof, just omit the word "longest". The argument is still valid.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, to hit the nail on the head, my question is why the chain must terminate at all. Do the preceding corollaries imply it?

Comment: @Herband: Recall the definition of dimension! Only finite chains are allowed at all. Although their lengths may be unbounded for weird spaces, one (usually) only looks at finite chains.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, okay. I feel some doubts. Let me take time to reread  what you wrote and the proof. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, also thanks.

Comment: @everyone, Laurent's comment under Martin's answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98549/existence-of-prime-ideals-and-axiom-of-choice/98573#98573 answers my question in the above comments. That is,  the Dependent Choice Axiom is needed to prove that ``every increasing sequence terminates'' implies the existence of maximal elements

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350489/show-that-kx-y-z-xz-y2-is-not-a-ufd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension of $k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2)$ is $2$. In geometric terms, its spectrum is an algebraic surface. But the dimension of $k[x,y,z]$ is $3$.

This computation relies on the following general result (see Qing Liu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Prop. 2.5.23): If $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field and $A$ is a domain, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $\dim(A/\mathfrak{p})+\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\dim(A)$. A corollary of this (2.5.26 loc. cit.) is that the dimension of $V(f) \subseteq X$ is $n-1$, where $X$ is an irreducible variety of dimension $n$ and $f$ is a regular function which is not nilpotent.

---

After your edit, the following might be of interest:

The homomorphism $k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2) \to k[s,t]$, $x \mapsto s^2$, $y \mapsto st$, $z \mapsto t^2$ is injective, and the image identifies with $k[s^2,t^2,st]$.

For the sake of completeness (and the hope that someone will explain me how to improve this), here is the proof for injectivity: Since $y^2-xz \in k[x,z][y]$ is monic, we see that $k[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ is free over $k[x,z]$ with basis $1,y$. Hence, it's free over $k$ with basis $x^{\mathbb{N}} z^{\mathbb{N}}$, $x^{\mathbb{N}} y z^{\mathbb{N}}$, which we can rewrite as $1,x^{\mathbb{N}^+} z^{\mathbb{N}^+}$, $x^{\mathbb{N}} y z^{\mathbb{N}}$. A typical element has the form $a + \sum_{i,j > 0} a_{ij} x^i z^j + \sum_{i,j > 0} b_{ij} x^i y z^j$. If it gets mapped to $0$, this means $a + \sum_{i,j > 0} a_{ij} s^{2i} t^{2j} + \sum_{i,j > 0} b_{ij} s^{2i+1} t^{2j+1}=0$. The three sums here don't share any monomial (consider the parities of the exponents). Thus they vanish individually. But also every monomial appears only once. Thus all coefficients vanish.

Actually this enables us to find a more ad hoc invariant (which coincides with the dimension, but one doesn't have to know  that) which distinguishes the two rings, namely the transzendence degree of the field of fractions over $k$. For $k[x,y,z]$ it is $3$. For $k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2)$ the field $k(s^2,st,t^2)$ contains $a := s/t$ and $b := s^2$; one checks that $s,t$ are algebraic over $k(a,b)$, and the latter is purely transcendent. Thus $\{a,b\}$ is a transcendence basis and the transcendence degree is $2$.

Comment: At Martin, thanks for both approaches. What do you think of my other question in the comments? Or should I ask it separately?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to avoid using Krull dimension. Given a $k$-algebra $A$ and a morphism $e_p : A \to k$ (which corresponds to evaluation at a point $p$ of $\text{Spec } A$), a **derivation** at $p$ is a linear map $D : A \to k$ such that
$$D(ab) = D(a) e_p(b) + e_p(a) D(b).$$

The space of all such $D$ is a vector space over $k$ which I'll denote by $T_p(A)$; geometrically it is the [Zariski tangent space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space) at $p$ ($D$ represents the directional derivative with respect to a tangent vector). More algebraically, a derivation at $p$ is a morphism 
$$\phi = e_p + \epsilon D : A \to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$$

such that composition with the natural quotient map $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2 \to k$ gives $e_p$.

This definition allows us to use the [universal property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) of polynomial rings to conclude that a derivation at any point for $k[x, y, z]$ is freely determined by $D(x), D(y)$, and $D(z)$; consequently $\dim T_p(k[x, y, z]) = 3$ for all $p$. On the other hand, a derivation $D : k[x, y, z]/(xz - y^2)$ at any point $p = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ with $y_0 \neq 0$ satisfies
$$D(y^2) = 2y_0 D(y) = D(xz) = z_0 D(x) + x_0 D(z)$$

hence $D(y)$ is determined by $D(x)$ and $D(z)$ (in characteristic not equal to $2$). Consequently $\dim T_p(k[x, y, z]/(xz - y^2)) = 2$.

(Note that when $p = (0, 0, 0)$ we instead have $\dim T_p(k[x, y, z]/(xz - y^2)) = 3$. This is a [singular point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety) of the variety $V(xz - y^2)$, so $k[x, y, z]/(xz - y^2)$ also cannot be isomorphic to $k[x, y]$ even though they have the same dimension.)

Comment: At Qiaochu, thanks for this third method, which also teaches me more. [In fact, I arrived at this coordinate ring while calculating the coordinate ring of the image of $P^1$ under the Veronese map $v_2$.]

Comment: At Qiaochu, I am afraid I should accept Martin's answer since he answered first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should except the answer which helped you most. Not the first one ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, Laurent's comment to your answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98549/existence-of-prime-ideals-and-axiom-of-choice/98573#98573 was the piece that was needed to answer my question in the comments, I guess. That is " the Dependent Choice Axiom is needed to prove that ``every increasing sequence terminates'' implies the existence of maximal elements". Am I right? I did not find this explicitly in any textbook of Algebraic Geometry that I have seen so far.