# unique factorization in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> I'm trying to show that $R := \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz),$ where $(x^2-yz)$ is the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ containing $x^2-yz,$ is not a unique factorization domain (UFD) by using the fact that in this ring $x^2 = yz,x,y,z$ are all irreducible and $x$ is not associates with $y$ or $z$.

However, I'm not sure how to show that $x,y,z$ are irreducible in this ring. Clearly I need to show that if $x=ab$ for some $a,b \in R,$ then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. I could show $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ using a degree argument, but I'm not sure if this is useful. I think I can show that $x$ is not associates with y or z. Suppose $x=uy$ for some unit $u$ in $R$. Then $x-uy \in (x^2-yz)$ so $x-uy = (f)(x^2-yz)$ for some $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z].$ But then since $u$ is a unit, there exists $v \in R$ so that $uv = 1.$ So $\deg(u),\deg(v) \leq 0$ (here $\deg(0) := -\infty$). But then $(f)(x^2-yz)$ cannot contain the term $x,$ a contradiction. Hence $x$ is not associates with $y$. A very similar argument shows that $x$ is not associates with $z$.

> How would one show that $x,y,z$ are irreducible in this ring? Also, did I correctly show that $x$ is not associates with $y$ or $z$?

Comment: Sorry, I originally linked https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350489/29335 but then noticed you are working over $\mathbb Z$.  We see this a lot using a field, but I don't recall seeing one with $\mathbb Z$.  You should still check, though, to see if any of the arguments works, and report what you find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof that $x$ is not associates with $y$ or $z$ is not quite correct, it does not follow that $uv=1$ in $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$, only in $R$.

But you are on the right track: In $x-uy=f\cdot(x^2-yz)$, the left-hand side contains the monomial $x$, but the right-hand side cannot.

---

For the irreducibility you can construct an isomoprhism $$R\to \mathbb Z[t^2,ts,s^2]$$ by sending $x\mapsto ts,y\mapsto t^2,z\mapsto s^2$.

Now for example $ts$ has only one nontrivial factorization $ts=t\cdot s$ in $\mathbb Z[t,s]$ and this factorization does not work in the subring $\mathbb Z[t^2,ts,s^2]$, thus $ts$ is irreducible in that ring and $x$ is irreducible in $R$.